# GAN Peformance is very low for time series HAR data augmentation

Tags: performance, time-series, generative-adversarial-network, data-augmentation

I have 3D time series data X Y Z for human activity recognition. I am using GAN for data augmentation but the generated data is very different of original data and accuracy is also very low when i am using that data to test my base modal.
I am using GAN implemented with fully connected layers(MLP).